# MySQLi.dll cannot be shared and PHP Deprecated

Tags: php, configuration, mysqli

While running my application I am getting the following errors

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/php_mysqli.dll' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/php_mysqli.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

and cronjobs are returning following error messages

```
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /usr/local/lib/php.ini on line 428 in Unknown on line 0
```

What does this mean? How to fix them. I have cPanel and WHM for my Server. I tried to fix some settings in PHP.ini but still the issue persists.

Comment: You are running in a Linux distro which cant load windows dll files, edit you php.ini and remove all extensions which have a dll in it

Comment: @Alex - Yes you are right, but how can I fix this problem in Linux?

Comment: update your post with your php.ini, i have to goto work now